# How to achieve N:M Relations with Attributes in Extbase?

Tags: typo3, relation, extbase

i was just trying to achieve a N:M relation between two of my Domain Models with an attribute.
I tried [this Tutorial](http://blog.undkonsorten.com/datenbankrelationen-typo3-irre-extension) ( sorry, it's german, but the code is fine. ) and everything works fine in the backend and the database (datarecords are created correctly, relations are visible in backend/tca config).

BUT: When I try to create a Model/Repository/Controller/Plugin ( all with minimal basic configurations, just for testing the output, so nothing fancy here ) and try to output my "firma" with the RepositoryMethod->findAll() I get an Error in SQL Syntax.

Extbase seems to access the wrong tables. Normally the SQL statement should ask for the mitarbeiterid/firmaid in the relation table. But the SQL-Error reveals that Extbase tries to find the column "firmaid" / "mitarbeiterid" in the "mitarbeiter"-table, where those columns do not exist.

Does anyone of you know if this can be fixed, or am I missing something from the tutorial (I'm aware that the first tutorial has some typing errors, but that'S not the problem :( ) ? I tried another tutorial [IRRE Tutorial](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/irre_tutorial) which is basically the same, just a bit more extended. Same SQL-Error in here. What has to be done to get some output in the frontend of these datarecords ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial seems to be outdated. seems to be more up to date and actually using extbase/fluid.

But lucky you, its not that hard to achieve what you are aiming for. You need to check this list. Make sure that

- Your class names, table names and folder structure are in synch with extbase expectations
- You have two domain models of which both have a property that contains a objectStorage that contains instances of the other object
- You have configured your TCA for both tables to use a mm table for the property containing the objectStorage

Comment: Looks like the Relation with attributes is not supported in Typo4.7 ( at least I've just read that ). Unfortunately I have to use it. But back to your comment: When I do what you say I just have a simple NM Relation between my two Domain Models. But I need an attribute that depends on the relation. Or am i misunderstanding you ? I guess I have to go for 2 n:m Tables/Relations and invent that extra Domain Model.